# how to create ExtJs 4 Tree inside accordion using store?

Tags: extjs, tree, accordion, datastore

I have an application with possibly 4 level menu,

i want to implement it with Accordion for first level and a tree inside each accordion panel.

how could i implement this with a store?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFQDl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example :

[ExtJS - Treepanel inside the Accordion Menu](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/52s)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Accordion Layout',
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        defaults: {
            // applied to each contained panel
            bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
        },
        layout: {
            // layout-specific configs go here
            type: 'accordion',
            titleCollapse: false,
            animate: true,
            activeOnTop: true
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Panel 1',
            id: 'panelOne',
            html: 'Panel content!'
        }, {
            title: 'Panel 2',
            html: 'Panel content!'
        }, {
            title: 'Panel 3',
            html: 'Panel content!'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                { text: "detention", leaf: true },
                { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                    { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                    { text: "algebra", leaf: true}
                ] },
                { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
            ]
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Tree',
        id: 'treePanel',
        header: false,
        width: 200,
        height: 150,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });    

    var panel = Ext.getCmp('panelOne');
    var tree = Ext.getCmp('treePanel');
    panel.add(tree);

});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i have this data http://jsonfiddle.net/h5eb4 , ii is a tree now, i want to know how to edit first level to automatically bind to an accordion an a tree inside each tab, is it possible or i need to extend the accordion to implement such a binding?

Comment: Ali, I didn't understand. Which node will be root node for menu?

Comment: it look like this now: http://i57.tinypic.com/29yjwo5.png, i want to make first level an accordion , level 2, 3, 4 will remain as a tree, i know how to make that in a library like knockoutJs , making some nested models an templates , and with single line of code i can bind that, but i'm new in extjs!

Comment: Ali, I will implement full code, just wait for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Ali,

here is the modified edition, hope it's right!

[ExtJS - TreePanel inside the Panel](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/53p)

```
Ext.define('AccModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id','text']
});

var accordion = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 400,
    height: 620,
    id: 'accordionPanel',
    defaults: {
        bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'accordion',
        titleCollapse: false,
        animate: true,
        activeOnTop: false
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

var addAccordion = function() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'treenode.json',
        success: function(response) {
            var nodes = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

            Ext.each(nodes, function(node) {
                accordion.add({
                    title: node.id,
                    id: node.id,
                    items: Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
                        header: false,
                        width: 380,
                        height: 600,
                        rootVisible: false,
                        root: {
                            expanded: false,
                            children: node.children
                        }
                    })
                });
            })
        }
    });
}

var init=function() {
    addAccordion();
}

Ext.onReady(function () {
    init();
});
```

Comment: thanks i get the point, i need to manually create accordion panels, and add tree inside theme, for example create an accordion panel for "Saramad.ERP.Accounting" and then add all children of it as a tree.

Comment: i used to do this in knockoutjs like this: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html

Comment: Ali, finally I think I resolved the issue but there is one problem. As you know, your json data has all information. We should divide json data by "Accordion Section". I tried everything but no success. I can load each part of tree inside the accordion but when I change the root node of the tree, the other accordion tree disappear. I will share the code as soon as possible.

Comment: Ali, finally I did it, check the code and fiddle please!

Comment: i wrote a similar code by extending panel class and loading all data in a treestore , but have no success. you saved my life.